# How do you declare a dependency injection C# class that uses generic Parameters?

Tags: dependency-injection, c#

I am using VS2022 and have this class

```
public class HttpClientModel<T>
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(T entity)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage message;

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        string url = "http://stuff";

        message = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, entity);

        if (message != null)
        {
            message = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized };
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

Usually, I'd set my injects up like this

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpClientModel, HttpClientModel>();
```

But how do I do it with a generic? Every way I tried just gives me an error. The entity class could be one of several (and more) once I get going. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us some examples of what you have tried and the errors they are giving.

Comment: for open generics use `builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(HttpClientModel<>), typeof(HttpClientModel<>));`